# JS function not working on dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code

```
function doCalc() {
var total = 0;
$('tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('input.subtotal').val($('input:eq(1)', this).val() * $('input:eq(2)', this).val());
});
$('.subtotal').each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).val());
});
$('#precio').val(total);
}
doCalc();

$('tr input').on('keyup', function() {
doCalc();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6ofbaLxb/3/

Its a table with dynamic rows, and js function to calculate values on "keyup". But i have a problem, the function only calculates the result when editing the first row. It does calculate results from the dynamic rows but only when edited the first row.

My Js knowledge is very basic so, i asking here if some knows a way to make it work with the dynamic rows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to implement [`event-delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) here,

```
$('table').on('keyup','tr input', doCalc);
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6ofbaLxb/10/)

---

And that button is not working because it does not have a div as parent, it is wrapped by td and tr. So try to remove that.

```
$(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest('tr').remove();
   x--;
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6ofbaLxb/14/)

Comment: Thanks you, that works fine. I just found out that the "Borrar" which is "remove" is not working. Do you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

From you code on jsfiddle, I noticed that

```
$('td input').on('keyup', function() {doCalc();});
```

loads when page loads, and does not affect on newer input tags
Add the same lines to

```
$(add_button).click(function(e)
```

Notice the difference here
https://jsfiddle.net/v27onw78/

Regarding the issue with removal using "borrar", try

```
$(this).parents('tr').remove();
```

The problem ccurs because you do not have a div tag in the parent alement to "borrar"

The same can be found here

https://jsfiddle.net/6ofbaLxb/15/

Comment: Your fix for the first bug (no event handler to recalculate numbers) is to add handlers to _all_ the rows every time you add a new row. This means some rows will have several copies of the handler. It doesn't really matter, since it's the handler just updates things and will update them to the same value the second time anyway, and since the number of handlers is unlikely to be large enough to slow things down noticeably. But it's still not very nice. In any case, Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy's answer is generally the preferred way.

Comment: Agreed David, event delegation does seem to be the better way to do it. It sure prevents additional system calls to add handler each time the function is called.